# How to install IntelliJ IDEA 13 in fresh ubuntu 14.04(64 bit)?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run the following command:

```
~/android/idea-IC-135.909/bin$ ./idea.sh
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: Cannot start IntelliJ IDEA
No JDK found. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: the errors says all, what you need?

Comment: I installed it. steps are

Comment: update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ~/softs/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100
    5  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ~/softs/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100
    6  java
    7  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ~/softs/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100
    8  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac ~/softs/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100
   11  cd softs/idea-IC-135.909/bin/
   12  ./idea.sh    
   21  cd ~
   22  gedit /etc/profile
   23  cd softs/android-sdk-linux/tools 
   34  sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
   35  sudo apt-get install lib32z1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you do not have JDK installed. The instruction for installing Oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu can be found at:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html